# Unable to load private key file .ppk (file format error)

Tags: ssh-keys

I generated an Ed25519 key pair with puttygen, and saved the private key on my computer.

When I try to authenticate with it, I get

```
Unable to load private key file "my_private_key.ppk" (file format error)
```

I checked that it really is a private key file, the file format should be correct as it it generated by puttygen.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

The version of Putty I used was too old, it did not support ed25519 at the time.
With the latest version (0.70), the error is gone.